# Word for "not able to be escaped from by struggling"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the word that means "not able to be escaped from by struggling"? I heard it many years ago and have forgotten it due to advancing age and mis-spent youth.

Comment: Can you expand on what word you want? Struggling makes the possibility of escape worse - like metaphorical quicksand?

Answer (score 1):

The verb **[ensnare](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ensnare)** seems to convey that sense

> to catch (an animal or person) in a trap or in a place from which there is no escape

I agree with mplungjan that *snared* can also work, but I think *ensnared* seems to connote *inescapable* a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

[Snared](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snare) comes to mind

> snare noun \ˈsner\
> : a device that has a loop (called a noose) which gets smaller when the end of it is pulled >and that is used to catch animals : a kind of trap
>
> : a position or situation from which it is difficult to escape

If someone/something is snared. struggling will only tighten the noose

Answer (score 0):

Forfoughten/
forfoughen is to be [Wearied and worn-out with fighting][1]

[1]: http://useful_english.enacademic.com/344472/forfoughten.  I think an appropriate word for a gentleman who is advancing in age and recalling a mis-spent youth

I thought 'laocooning' would be a struggle word but I cannot find any use

Answer (score 0):

A synonym of "inescapable" is "ineluctable".

This is what the online *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* says about "ineluctable":

> Not to be avoided or escaped; inevitable: "Those war plans rested on a belief in the ineluctable superiority of the offense over the defense" (Jack Beatty).
>   [Latin inēluctābilis : in-, not; see IN-1 + ēluctābilis, penetrable (from ēluctārī, to struggle out of : ex-, ex- + luctārī, to struggle).]
>   ineluctability n.
>   ineluctably adv.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "to be hogtied" and "to be in a double bind."

> [hogtie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogtie#Figurative_use): to make incapable of effective action, as if by tying up.
>
> [double bind](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/double+bind): a situation of conflict from which there's no escape.

Answer (score -2):

May be we can use sustainability...